# How to plot the typical bowl shape when illustrating gradient descent with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

When illustrating gradient descent, we usually see the bowl shape graph below. Also, it is said that using log_loss instead of squared error, we can find minimum value of loss more easily, as using squared error as loss function, may result in multiple local minimum values.

Therefore, I want to plot the bowl shape graph like below.

[image]

However, I only managed to plot the following 
[image]

Here is my code, could anyone help me fix it? thanks

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import math


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 5), subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

# Get the test data
x1 = 1
x2 = 1
y = 0.8
w = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
# w = np.random.random(100)
wl = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
# wl = np.random.random(100)
w1 = np.ones((100,100))
w2 = np.ones((100,100))
for idx in range(100):
    w1[idx] = w1[idx]*w
    w2[:,idx] = w2[:,idx]*wl

L = []
for i in range(w1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(w1.shape[1]):
        a = w1[i,j]*x1 + w2[i,j]*x2
        f = 1/(1+math.exp(-a))
        l = -(y*math.log(f)+(1-y)*math.log(1-f))
        # l = (1/2)*(f-y)**2
        L.append(l)
l = np.array(L).reshape(w1.shape)


ax1.plot_wireframe(w1,w2,l)
ax1.set_title("plot backpropogation")


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not understand the formula. Is this question about getting the math correct or about plotting?

Comment: it is about plotting, I want to the bowl shape graph above all.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following ignores the Formula from the question and is probably completely unrelated to any actual problem. It just shows how to plot a bowl.

A way to plot a bowl is to use a function that is rotationally symmetric about the z axis.

For example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5), 
                        subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

alpha = 0.8
r = np.linspace(-alpha,alpha,100)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(r,r)
l = 1./(1+np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2)))

ax1.plot_wireframe(X,Y,l)
ax1.set_title("plot")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. May I push one step further? Do you think loglikelihood function is more likely to produce bowl shape graph (with single minimum value) and squared error function is more like to produce wave shape graph (with multiple minimum values)?

Comment: I don't think it will depend on that. But as I said, all I've shown here is independent on gradient descent. It just shows you the method to draw a bowl.